# ASCX file in Sharepoint 2007 page layout - set field values in edit mode?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2007, ascx, page-layout

I have two user control (`ASCX`) files in a SharePoint solution package. The controls are already working fine, but I've had to create 8 different page layouts for the various parameters that the control files accept in order to have the the desired data displayed on the various pages that will display them.

I'm wondering if there is any way to set the values of the control files' public fields in the edit mode of the page that uses the page layout in order to maximize modularity (this way I can have one page layout for each of the two user controls and set the parameters as needed at the publishing stage.) I guess I'm asking if it's possible to dynamically set control file parameters like this:

```
FieldParamValue = "SomeValue";

<UserControl:ControlTag ID="SomeControlFile" runat="server" MyFieldParameter=FieldParamValue />
```

and then have the `FieldParamValue` be an editable option in the SharePoint published page while in edit mode.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it with the control itself, but if it were a webpart, you certainly could do it this way.

Comment: Thanks, @DustinDavis. I'll have to look into developing webparts for this solution in future revisions. For now I'll just deploy the solution as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the opposite. On your user control, on init check the current page layout (using the PublishingPage object) and depending on the page layout, provision / adapt required properties of your user control.

Comment: Hrm... that seems relatively similar, albeit in a more round-about way, to passing the hard-coded parameter to the control via the MyFieldParameter="parameter" method. BUT it's an interesting concept that could definitely have uses in other situations. I'll have to look into what data is passed in the PublishingPage object and see if there's a way to dynamically grab the value of an 'edit mode' panel... that might do the trick.